# Live USB for Ubuntu 12.10 doesn't boot

Tags: 12.10, system-installation, live-usb

I'm having some trouble installing Ubuntu 12.10 on my laptop. I downloaded the iso file from ubuntu and with startup disk creator created startup on mu usb-stick. I changed the boot sequence from hdd to ext usb. But no luck. Also created a bootable CD, put it on first boot sequence and also this doesn't work. My old OS is Natty 11.04.

I'm looking for a solution.

Remmie

Comment: Have you tried manually setting the boot device, at startup (and not using boot-order)?

Comment: Make sure that the USB is FAT32 formatted.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) for create boot flash. Its avilable for Linux, Windows & Mac OS X.
Easy to use, and correct create boot records on my flash.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps your pendrive has failed to become bootable ...

this is the way to do it ... follow steps shown here :

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

your main problem is that your device hasnt become bootable thats it !!!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.